# Executing an SOQL on the record id, created from Process Builder, returns empty result

Tags: apex, process-builder

I'm trying to execute an Apex action in a process Builder which is set to Fire on Create of new Record.

In that Apex action, I'm executing an SOQL and reading other fields of the record (`record id` is passed as `input parameter` into `Apex Action` of `Process Builder`).

But that query is returning `empty result`.

Is this a restriction in apex action. It seems like that the Create record is not yet committed into database when the Apex Action is fired. Is there any workaround available to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, I've to use Async Apex calling (such as `@future` or `batch apex`) to make this work. The `Synchronous Apex` SOQL retrieval happens before records are committed to database when used from Process Builder, so I had to use Future method to make my functionality work from process builder.

Comment: But you can query for the records in `after insert`. And `Process Builder` executes after that. So you would think the `Id` should be defined.

Comment: That isnt the use case. I m developing a function that could be executed via apex from Process Builder. Now, i ve confirmed tested it that process builder passes the newly created record as input parameter but when u run soql on that record id to fetch other fields data it returns 0 records. Only way it returns 1 record when i execute it in Asynchronous way, that is, make the method call a @Future method. Triggers cannot be used here as my sole purpose is ti make call from process builder as user created Action in it.